# What is the difference between WITH Query and SELECT Query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Data : I have written two queries one is WITH and Other is SELECT and then self joining the table below, but both queries return different results, why it happens ?

table name is **test_cur**

```
    ID_SOURCE_CUR   ID_TARGET_CUR
 -------------  --------------
    A               B
    B               C
    C               D
    D               E
    A               Z
    G               A
    K               A
    Q               A
    J               J
    K               K
    K               L
    L               K
    B               A
    Z               A
```

So why the two queries below return different results ?

```
    SELECT *
      FROM test_cur tu, test_cur fu
     WHERE tu.id_target_cur = 'A'
       AND fu.id_source_cur = 'A'
       AND tu.id_source_cur <> fu.id_target_cur;

returns 8 rows.

ID_SOURCE_CUR   ID_TARGET_CUR   ID_SOURCE_CUR_1 ID_TARGET_CUR_1
--------------  --------------   --------------  -------------- 
    G               A               A               B
    K               A               A               B
    Q               A               A               B
    Z               A               A               B
    G               A               A               Z
    K               A               A               Z
    Q               A               A               Z
    B               A               A               Z
```

And -

```
    WITH qry1 AS
         (SELECT *
            FROM test_cur)
    SELECT *
      FROM qry1 tu, qry1 fu
     WHERE tu.id_target_cur = 'A'
       AND fu.id_target_cur = 'A'
       AND tu.id_source_cur <> fu.id_target_cur;

    returns 25 rows.

ID_SOURCE_CUR   ID_TARGET_CUR   ID_SOURCE_CUR_1 ID_TARGET_CUR_1
--------------  --------------   --------------  -------------- 
        G               A               G               A
        G               A               K               A
        G               A               Q               A
        G               A               B               A
        G               A               Z               A
        K               A               G               A
        K               A               K               A
        K               A               Q               A
        K               A               B               A
        K               A               Z               A
        Q               A               G               A
        Q               A               K               A
        Q               A               Q               A
        Q               A               B               A
        Q               A               Z               A
        B               A               G               A
        B               A               K               A
        B               A               Q               A
        B               A               B               A
        B               A               Z               A
        Z               A               G               A
        Z               A               K               A
        Z               A               Q               A
        Z               A               B               A
        Z               A               Z               A
```

Why ?

Comment: the 2 where clauses are different `fu.id_source_cur = 'A'` vs. `fu.id_target_cur = 'A'`

Answer (score 5):

Your second query is different, you have a different `WHERE` clause. The first `WHERE` is :

```
WHERE tu.id_target_cur = 'A'
       AND fu.id_source_cur = 'A'
       AND tu.id_source_cur <> fu.id_target_cur;
```

The second is:

```
WHERE tu.id_target_cur = 'A'
       AND fu.id_target_cur = 'A' -- this line is different, it should be fu.id_source_cur = 'A'
       AND tu.id_source_cur <> fu.id_target_cur;
```

Change those and the results are the exact same on both queries.

Answer (score 3):

The where clauses are different `fu.id_source_cur = 'A'` vs. `fu.id_target_cur = 'A'`